# Peer dependency for peer dependency

Tags: node.js, dependency-management, yarnpkg, package.json

Here is my current modules hierarchy:
[image]
I'm writing the `Module` (which has green background and is inside dotted square).
It has `DepA` dependency which has `DepB` peer dependency.

My module is kind of a config-helper for the main `App`.
`Module` does not use `DepB` itself.
But it helps to work with `DepB` via `DepA`.

The `App` works with `DepB` and has it as a dependency (regular).

So, I was thinking that this `DepB` should be a peer dependency in the `Module`.
But that does not work.
It leads to `unmet peer dependency` problem: `DepA` expects to find it "inside" `Module`.

Why can't I proxy that peer dependency to the `App` which actually uses it?
What are the best practices for that kind of situation?

---

**Update**

The question is not relevant.
See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG, that was my fault!

While testing `Module` I did `require('../')` instead of `require('@my/module')`.
By that I was trying to avoid re-installation on every change.
That was the root of all incorrect module resolution issues.